# IntentService within an IntentService. Will it work?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I'm a beginner in Android programming, and I was just reading up on IntentServices. I have a doubt - If I issue a call to another class extending IntentService from within a class extending IntentService, will the call be valid?

As an overview, something like this -

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService{
    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
        //do stuff with incoming intent
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ABC.class);
        //ABC.class is another class extending IntentService
        startService(newIntent);
    }
}
```

Will this work?

Comment: your example is wrong. you are starting an activity from service

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @RahulKulhalli It looks like you accepted an answer that no longer answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start activities from an Intent Service, but you need to add the NEW_TASK flag to it.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

You can also start another IntentService from an IntentService.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that part up for me! :) As a side note, will I need to make any special changes/additions in the Manifest.xml?

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK only use for startActivity in service, right ?

Comment: @GiapLee Well, then if I want to issue the startService method, what flags will I need to add to the Intent?

Comment: i never use this case before, but i guess still use that flag too for IntentService

Comment: @GiapLee Cool. I'll try it out and see. :)